# Double Spawn in the last zone

Tags: zombicide-black-plague

If I draw a Double Spawn card in the last zone in a spawning spree, I must use that for the first zone. But since I already spawned one card there, should I spawn **one more** or **two more** cards? Example: I have 3 spawn points. Spawn first, one walker, second, 1 fatty, third, double zombies. Now should I draw one or two cards for the first zone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the Double Spawn card is drawn for the last Spawn Zone
>   or building Zone, use it for an extra double Spawn on the first
>   Spawn Zone or first building Zone (even if you previously
>   spawned Zombies in it!).

"Extra" means "added to an existing or usual amount or number", so two more cards.

Comment: So in the end there will be 3 spawns in the zone; that first one and two after the double zombies?